# How does dafny encode the validation of conditions involving arrays?

Tags: z3, dafny

I'm evaluating the use Dafny, compared to the direct use of z3 for encoding a problem we have in my company.

While trying out the z3 API I noticed that there is an Array type, which seems to resemble a lot the way Z3 implements total functions. It seems like there is not an easy way to reason on the Lenght of such arrays in Z3.

If we look at Dafny, it can easily prove the following correct

```
method Find(a: array<int>) returns (index: int)
   ensures index == a.Length
{
   index := a.Length;
}
```

Now, for me the question is:

*How is the array used by Dafny encoded in Z3?*

Let's say that Dafny doesn't actually use Z3 arrays, where can I find some documentation on the way Dafny abstract things that do not identify a bounded number of variables in Z3 (such as array)? Same question applies for any object that is heap allocated, does it use allocation-site abstractions or something else?

Answer (score 0):

There's really no magic, nor anything "implicit" that guarantees all array accesses are within bounds. You can surely write Dafny programs that index out-of-bounds, you just cannot prove useful things for them. Dafny makes you do this, by generating the necessary "in-bounds" check; but it's still up to you to have the proof go through by putting in the necessary annotations. Is that what you're looking for? This is also explained here:  https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/tutorialcontent/guide#h27